# How to open a file automatically while entering vim

Tags: autocmd

I know that we can open a file with the help of the argument `-o` of vim: `vim -o myfile`.

But for some reason I can't pass any argument when I execute the command `vim`. So I'm thinking if it is possible to open a file while entering vim with the help of vim config / vim script.

I've made the plugin `Nerdtree` to be autoloaded while entering vim:

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
```

So is there some similar thing to open a file automatically? Something like `autocmd BufEnter OpenMyfile`?

In a word, I want to achieve this: after executing the command `vim`, the plugin `Nerdtree` will be autoloaded, and a file will be auto-opened (instead of an empty buffer).

Comment: Please explain: "But for some reason I can't pass any argument when I execute the command vim. "

Comment: @Ralf  The reason is: I set some configs for Nerdtree, which are a series of  heavy actions. If I run `vim -o myfile`, it will first show the content of `myfile` and then `Nerdtree` will popup. There is a little delay so that I can see the window moving.

Comment: @Ralf So I'm thinking if I can load `Nerdtree` first and then show the content of `myfile`, it would be great.

Comment: "Loading plugin" is a one thing; "opening a window" is another. If you want to open some window or switch to a buffer then... open a window and switch to a buffer. `:new`, `:vnew +X`, `:edit filename` and so on, and so on.

Comment: Whats wrong with just "vim myfile.txt"?

Comment: @Dmitry   `myfile.txt` is an ASCII image file. I want to make it open automatically when I execute `vim`.

Comment: @Matt  `myfile.txt` is an ASCII image file. I want to make it open automatically when I execute `vim`.  For now, I make `alias vim=vim -o ~/.vim/myfile.txt`. It works but it will open `myfile.txt` first and then load the plugin `Nerdtree`. When I execute `vim`, I can see that `myfile.txt` is opened but it move towards right to make some space for `Nerdtree`. So I'm thinking if I can load `Nerdtree` first and then open `myfile.txt`. Of course, I want to make all of these happen automatically.

Comment: Does ``vim -c "e myfile.txt"`` help?